# How to integrate storybook into react-native package 'create-react-native-library'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, storybook

Hi i want to run `storybook` in a react-native **package**, that i have created with `create-react-native-library`.

So, the steps i ve done, in order to havethe package up and running are:

1. from the react-native documentation : https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-setup
2. Run `npx create-react-native-library@latest react-native-awesome-module` // create a simple package
3. in the `examples`folder, run `yarn start` so it loads on the `iPhone` simulator.
4. Because it is a **package** and not an **application**, i want to have storybook inside it, so to visualize the components.
5. Install storybook like so: `npx -p @storybook/cli sb init --type react`

The `yarn storybook` command gives error like so: **Error: Cannot find module 'react-dom/package.json'**

I attach a screenshot for reference:
[image]

So, is there a way to integrate the **storybook** into this package ? Do i miss anything ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Storybook for React Native | Documentation](https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/intro-to-storybook/react-native/en/get-started/),

You have to specify the `--type` as `react_native` **not** `react`.

```
npx -p @storybook/cli sb init --type react_native
```

Answer (score 1):

To use storybook with react native you have to change `--type` to `react_native`.

This means, that your command to initialize storybook will be:

```
npx -p @storybook/cli sb init --type react_native
```